# Complex validations on Schema Registry?

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-schema-registry

Reading the following article https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/schema-registry/index.html I want to use it to check on the incoming JSON fields but also, perform a certain conditional validation to the fields incoming.

Is it possible to do "if this field == x_value, this other field has to be present or have this other value" kind of validations in the Schema Registry?

If not, which is the workaround to perform validations prior putting the message in the Kafka topic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Registry itself doesn't do any validations such as this.

You'd need to build such logical validations in your serializer.

JSONSchema is the only type that can do similar validations, but only per-field, I believe. Plain JSON records cannot be validated by the registry at all (out of the box), so you'd have to write your own serializer to do that, anyway.

Otherwise, in JVM projects, for example, `javax.valiation` , Hibernate validator, Apache Commons Validation, etc. can all be used to validate POJOs *before* they get serialized into a Kafka record.

Or, add to a consumer's deserializer, then you'll need to try-catch the validation process, and skip/log/error on invalid records.